# Apple WiFi profile - prevent changes

Tags: mac-osx, wifi, mac

We are using an XML profile (Generated with Apple Configurator) to configure our mac's wifi settings. The main thing we wish to control is SSID Auto-Join, which should be off.

We can set this in the profile and it works. However, a user is able to manually remove the wifi network from the system preferences. If they manually add it back, then Auto-Join will be enabled. The only way to fix this, is to re-install the profile.

Does anyone know of a way to either:
a) Detect that Auto-Join is enabled on a WiFi network from the command line
or
b) Prevent changes to WiFI networks when there is a profile controlling the network.

Help is appreciated, thanks!